# how to fetch next 4 weekdays name from a particular day?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i need to get next few days name from a particular day. like given day name is Friday and i need to get next 4 like Saturday, Sunday, Monday and Tuesday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .....

```
  String[] days=new String[] {"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};


    private ArrayList<String> getNextFourDays(String day)
    {
        int index=-1;
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<days.length;i++) {
            if(days[i].equalsIgnoreCase(day)) {
                index=i;
                break;
            }
        }


        if(index==-1)
        {
            return null;
        }


        ArrayList<String> nextFourDays=new ArrayList<>();

        for(int j=index+1;count<4;j++) {
            if(j>=days.length) {
                j=0;
            }
            nextFourDays.add(days[j]);
            count++;
        }

        return nextFourDays;

    }
```

Note: it will return null if the invalid day is passed other than the string[] days valid and case has no effect

Answer (score 1):

It's aready answered but you can do it with much cleaner code and moderner APIs: OneLiner

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<DayOfWeek> nextDaysList = IntStream.range(1, 5).mapToObj(x -> DayOfWeek.FRIDAY.plus(x))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would use the java.time DayOfWeek enum for type safety instead of strings suggested by other answers.

If you are using kotlin you can even define an extension function like this:

```
fun DayOfWeek.getFollowingDays(n: Int): List<DayOfWeek> {
    val list: MutableList<DayOfWeek> = mutableListOf()
    var tempDay = this
    for (i in 0 until n) {
        tempDay = tempDay.plus(1)
        list.add(tempDay)
    }
    return list
}
```

Then you can call the extension function like this:

```
DayOfWeek.FRIDAY.getFollowingDays(4)
```

and the result would be

```
[SATURDAY, SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY]
```

The advantage of using enum instead of a string is that the compiler will catch any errors for you and your app will not crash/have undesired behaviour at runtime. If day is represented as a string you can pass any possible string (like "Invalid Day!") which might cause the program to act unexpectedly at runtime. However, by using enums there is no possible way to misuse it, you *need* to call it on a day defined by the enum otherwise the app won't build.